# Query DE from Child BU to Another Child BU

Tags: marketing-cloud

Is there a way to query from child BU to another child BU DE's? For example I am in ABC child BU and I want to query DE which reside in XYZ child BU?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but only if the DEs are in Shared Data Extensions.

Comment: No, they are not. That's the problem.

Comment: That's the only way you can do it.